# Searching HTML string for links (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, web-scraping, html-parsing

This might be a bit confusing as I am a bit *new* to Objective-C. I have the app already getting the source code:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"google.com"];
NSString *webData= [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:URL encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
```

That gets the source code correctly, I've logged it and checked. I want to find only the links inside that string, so anything with the keyword:

```
<a href
```

I've tried searching the string, like so:

```
 if ([webData containsString:@"<a href="]) {
    NSLog(@"string contains!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"string does not contain");
}
```

It always returns negative, and I don't understand why. I want to get only the lines of code that contain the links and set those lines to a new string. The string will contain all the links on the source, but I don't know how to do that. I hope I've given enough information, and if you have any questions about my issue please ask. Thanks.

**EDIT 1**
I've tried the answer given, and this is my following code

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"google.com"];
NSString *webData= [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:URL encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\<a href=\"(.*)\".*<\/a\>"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];
NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex matchesInString:webData
                                                    options:0
                                                      range:NSMakeRange(0, [webData length])];
```

It first doesn't work, and I get the following errors/warnings: [warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llLMS.png)

**EDIT 2**
I've tried fixing the code, and my current is

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"google.com"];
NSString *webData= [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:URL encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\<a.+?\\>.+?\\<\\/a\\>"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:webData
                          options:0
                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [webData length])];
NSLog(@"%@", matches);
```

This is the log that's being outputted:

```
2018-11-05 00:12:51.144009-0500 InjectionTest[42684:6739102] (
"<NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x6000037b2c00>{25654, 124}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x600002ca0210> \\<a.+?\\>.+?\\<\\/a\\> 0x1}",
"<NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x6000037b2cc0>{38864, 316}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x600002ca0210> \\<a.+?\\>.+?\\<\\/a\\> 0x1}",
"<NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x6000037b2340>{39939, 105}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x600002ca0210> \\<a.+?\\>.+?\\<\\/a\\> 0x1}",
"<NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x6000037b2100>{40051, 103}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x600002ca0210> \\<a.+?\\>.+?\\<\\/a\\> 0x1}",
"<NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x6000037b2000>{40203, 125}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x600002ca0210> \\<a.+?\\>.+?\\<\\/a\\> 0x1}",
"<NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x6000037b2140>{41190, 91}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x600002ca0210> \\<a.+?\\>.+?\\<\\/a\\> 0x1}",
"<NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x6000037b0f00>{41297, 67}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x600002ca0210> \\<a.+?\\>.+?\\<\\/a\\> 0x1}",
"<NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x6000037b2d80>{41479, 124}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x600002ca0210> \\<a.+?\\>.+?\\<\\/a\\> 0x1}"
```

)

I'm pretty sure that's not what I'm supposed to be getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using `NSRegularExpression` instead:

By using appropriate pattern, for example:

```
\<a href=\"(.*)\".*<\/a\>
```

with following function:

```
 matchesInString:options:range:
```

You will get a list of `A` elements in your HTML string.

More details, read here in official Apple document:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression?language=objc

** **Update** **

Sample code that extract all `<a>` elements from html text:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"];
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\<a.+?\\>.+?\\<\\/a\\>"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:html options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, html.length)];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    NSRange matchRange = [match range];
    NSString *matchedString = [html substringWithRange:matchRange];
    NSLog(@"%@", matchedString);
}
```

Here is the log from above code:

```
2018-11-05 14:30:01.252702 TestArray[1322:320814] <a class=gb1 href="https://www.google.co.jp/imghp?hl=ja&tab=wi">&#30011;&#20687;</a>
2018-11-05 14:30:01.252911 TestArray[1322:320814] <a class=gb1 href="https://maps.google.co.jp/maps?hl=ja&tab=wl">&#12510;&#12483;&#12503;</a>
2018-11-05 14:30:01.253120 TestArray[1322:320814] <a class=gb1 href="https://play.google.com/?hl=ja&tab=w8">Play</a>
2018-11-05 14:30:01.253346 TestArray[1322:320814] <a class=gb1 href="https://www.youtube.com/?gl=JP&tab=w1">YouTube</a>
2018-11-05 14:30:01.253512 TestArray[1322:320814] <a class=gb1 href="https://news.google.co.jp/nwshp?hl=ja&tab=wn">&#12491;&#12517;&#12540;&#12473;</a>
2018-11-05 14:30:01.253638 TestArray[1322:320814] <a class=gb1 href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm">Gmail</a>
2018-11-05 14:30:01.253750 TestArray[1322:320814] <a class=gb1 href="https://drive.google.com/?tab=wo">&#12489;&#12521;&#12452;&#12502;</a>
2018-11-05 14:30:01.253934 TestArray[1322:320814] <a class=gb1 style="text-decoration:none" href="https://www.google.co.jp/intl/ja/options/"><u>&#12418;&#12387;&#12392;&#35211;&#12427;</u> &raquo;</a>
2018-11-05 14:30:01.254049 TestArray[1322:320814] <a href="http://www.google.co.jp/history/optout?hl=ja" class=gb4>&#12454;&#12455;&#12502;&#23653;&#27508;</a>
2018-11-05 14:30:01.254164 TestArray[1322:320814] <a  href="/preferences?hl=ja" class=gb4>&#35373;&#23450;</a>
2018-11-05 14:30:01.254274 TestArray[1322:320814] <a target=_top id=gb_70 href="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=ja&passive=true&continue=https://www.google.com/" class=gb4>&#12525;&#12464;&#12452;&#12531;</a>
2018-11-05 14:30:01.254434 TestArray[1322:320814] <a href="/advanced_search?hl=ja&amp;authuser=0">&#26908;&#32034;&#12458;&#12503;&#12471;&#12519;&#12531;</a>
2018-11-05 14:30:01.254739 TestArray[1322:320814] <a href="/language_tools?hl=ja&amp;authuser=0">&#35328;&#35486;&#12484;&#12540;&#12523;</a>
2018-11-05 14:30:01.254900 TestArray[1322:320814] <a href="https://www.google.com/setprefs?sig=0_hs-qGLtJFycvdIdXbi2jQdSOY4s%3D&amp;hl=en&amp;source=homepage&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwi_tb7pwrzeAhULwLwKHZ9aDiAQ2ZgBCAU">English</a>
2018-11-05 14:30:01.255072 TestArray[1322:320814] <a href="/intl/ja/ads/">&#24195;&#21578;&#25522;&#36617;</a>
2018-11-05 14:30:01.255182 TestArray[1322:320814] <a href="http://www.google.co.jp/intl/ja/services/">&#12499;&#12472;&#12493;&#12473; &#12477;&#12522;&#12517;&#12540;&#12471;&#12519;&#12531;</a>
2018-11-05 14:30:01.255453 TestArray[1322:320814] <a href="https://plus.google.com/115899767381375908215" rel="publisher">+Google</a>
2018-11-05 14:30:01.255609 TestArray[1322:320814] <a href="/intl/ja/about.html">Google &#12395;&#12388;&#12356;&#12390;</a>
2018-11-05 14:30:01.255722 TestArray[1322:320814] <a href="https://www.google.com/setprefdomain?prefdom=JP&amp;prev=https://www.google.co.jp/&amp;sig=K_erqW_iZ2bjJu2TsKii5UfNnAGcg%3D">Google.co.jp</a>
2018-11-05 14:30:01.255832 TestArray[1322:320814] <a href="/intl/ja/policies/privacy/">&#12503;&#12521;&#12452;&#12496;&#12471;&#12540;</a>
2018-11-05 14:30:01.256001 TestArray[1322:320814] <a href="/intl/ja/policies/terms/">&#35215;&#32004;</a>
```

Comment: I've tried what I think you've said, but I've gotten an error. I'll edit my original post to show code and error. It also doesn't work, and I don't know if I did anything wrong.

Comment: First, `matchesInString` returns an `NSArray` of matching elements instead of `UInteger`. Next, I wrote the pattern using javascript syntax hence it requires modification to work in ObjC. The correct pattern should be something like this: `@"\\<a.+?\\>.+?\\<\\/a\\>"`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've updated my post, and I still have an issue. I'm sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: From the log, you are coming closer to the final result. Next you need to extract `<a>` element string using `matches` array. See my update for example code.

Comment: Thanks Ryan! I've marked your Answer as correct, but I have one question. Say if I wanted to find the links on a website that requires a password, how would I do that? I used google for a very known example. I already have a successful Javascript Injection that logs into the website, but I feel like that's not working for pulling <a href. Is there anything I'd have to do otherwise? Like a `POST` or something? I apologize for not using the main website to begin with.

Comment: What did you mean by `find the links on a website that requires a password`?

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't making sense. I mean that say if I have a university website that requires a password to get into. I want to access a page's source that requires a password. For example, like a list of classes or a calendar. A page source that requires a password to access that webpage is what I'm trying to get at.

Comment: Ok, so if I understood correctly then you want to find the link that lead to a login page or something like that in a list of links?

Comment: No, I want to go to a page that has a list of classes and on each of the class names, there IS a link to more information of that class. The page that shows classes requires login, and I want to be able to log in, then get that page's `<a href` and determine which one to travel to.

Comment: Ah! I get it. Then that could be a long story. The idea is: You load the link of classes into a `UIWebView`, inject javascript code to the page using `evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler:` function. Your javascipt code will then find the login form, fill them with appropriate credential and invoke form submit. If you do that carefully & correctly, you'll have a great chance to be landing on the classes page.

Comment: That's the way of doing all your required stuffs with `UIWebView`. If you don't want to use `UIWebView` then you must use `NSURLRequest` or network framework such as `AFNetworking` instead of fetching webpage with `stringWithContentsOfURL`. Why? You need a mechanical to keep your login session which `stringWithContentsOfURL` cannot do.

Comment: Thanks! DO you mind elaborating on that? I'm sure I could figure it out, but if you could that'd be nice! Also, thanks so much for your continued help

Comment: Unfortunately, 600 characters limit in comment is not enough for elaborating on the stuffs you want to do. In what approach do you want more detail?

Comment: I'm confused mostly on how to get the page source while staying logged in. I could care less about the `UIWebView`. My current code is already in my question, and I just want to know how to change it. I've googled `AFNetworking` and the answers weren't really helpful.

Comment: Ok, so you will want to stick with `NSURLRequest` or `AFNetworking` framework. If you already know how to use them, its fine. Otherwise, search around SO for the usage tutor. Then no matter what you are using, you must first send a `POST` request with credential to login. The response will return back to you a session cookies. You then set the cookies to http header of any request you want to send from that time onward. That's all. Again, looking around SO to know how to set cookies for http request.

Comment: I've successfully done a `POST` request, but I have 2 issues/questions. When I get the page source, it gives the source for a page loading, please wait. I've added a button to get the source again, which is successful, but was wondering any other more ideal ways of doing that. My final question is about setting the cookies for the request. I've browsed SO, and didn't really find anything helpful. I'm currently just re-posting every time I want to get source which I know isn't ideal. How would I do that? Or could you link me a post or video?

Comment: The number of requests depend on the way server react to your login. If it's a redirect response then you need to modify your code to follow redirection (search for it on SO). If the redirection is manually trigger by javascript or whatever, then another request is required. I suggest using HTTP client tool such as `postman`, send your request with it to learn the way server react to your request first. Lastly, it may not making any sense to suggest how to set request cookies, unless I know what framework are you using.